# Invoicing developers with Windows Azure API Management service

Tags: azure, service, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management

I am looking for any option in Windows Azure API Management service, so that I may invoice/cost developers consuming my Web API, as per their number of calls to Web API. Everything I found under this service is quite easy to use and promising, including analytic which shows maximum details of how many times each endpoint is hit etc. The last thing I need is if there is a way I can attach some pricing model with Web API so that I can see total cost invoiced towards a particular developer/consumer for API calls he made.

Answer (score 1):

Azure API Management doesn't have direct support for payments/invoicing. We are working on the management API (coming soon) that could be used for integration with 3rd party billing providers. Would love to hear more about you scenario - please email to apimgmt@microsoft.com

Comment: Its been really nice to hear back from you Vlad. Will send email to specified address. Thanks.